# Error while using auto as the function return type

Tags: c++, function, c++17, auto

I am learning C++ using the resources listed here. In particular, i read that we can use the **auto type specifier** as the return type of a function. So to get clarity over the concept, i tried the following example:

**header.h**

```
#pragma once
struct S 
{
    auto f();
};
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

auto S::f() 
{
    return 4;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
    S s;
    s.f();
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives me error saying:

```
main.cpp:7:9: error: use of ‘auto S::f()’ before deduction of ‘auto’
    7 |     s.f();
      |         ^
```

My question is why am i getting this error and how to solve this.

Comment: Similar problem: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **problem** is that the function definition **must be visible** at any point where the function(with `auto` return type as in your case) is used. Since you've defined(implemented) that member function inside a source file(.cpp), it is not visible when the call expression `s.f()` is encountered.

To **solve** this you can put the implementation of the member function inside the header and make use of `inline` keyword as shown below:

**header.h**

```
#pragma once
struct S 
{
    auto f();
};

inline auto S::f() //note the use of inline to avoid multiple definition error
{
    return 4;
}
```

Note that we've used `inline` because we've implemented the member function in a header file which will be included in many other source files. That is, to avoid multiple definition error.

Answer (score 7):

When the compiler hits this part of the code:

```
S s;
s.f();
```

All it has seen is the contents of the header `header.h`. If we look in there we can see that the compiler will only get to look at:

```
struct S 
{
    auto f();
};
```

How is it supposed to know the return type of `f` from just this? Answer is, it cannot. So you need to make the definition of `f` available **where it is used**. That means you need to put it in the header file:

```
struct S 
{
    auto f() {
        return 4;
    }
};
/// or
inline auto S::f() { return 4; }
```

Or better yet, don't abuse `auto` here. `auto` can be useful when the type must be deduced because it depends on a template parameter or similar. In your case, the type is very well defined, so it is easier for the user, if you just use it:

```
struct S {
    int f();  
}
```